# How do you relate table in power bi to perform a calculation

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[image]

I need to calculate ProductPrice[overall] * DealerProduct[quantity] but the tables aren't related. I have been trying to use Sumx with related table but no matter what I do I cant get it to display the correct information.

I am currently trying to create a column in ProductPrice to just get the quantity in this table but I don't even know if that's possible.

So far I have tried:

Column in ProductPrice -
SUMX(RELATEDTABLE(DealerProduct),ProductPrice[overall]).

Column in ProductPrice -
SUMX(RELATEDTABLE(DealerProduct),DealerProduct[quantity]).

Column in ProductPrice -
CALCULATE(SUMX(RELATEDTABLE(DealerProduct),DealerProduct[quantity]) / COUNTROWS(DealerProduct))

So far the last one has been closest but still off.

Anyone have any ideas here?

DealerProduct:
[image]

ProductPrice:
[image]

Comment: Why isn't ProductPrice related to DealerProduct instead of directly to Dealer?

Comment: And why related table() ? If you are on many side, and you try to access the columns of a table on the one side, then the function you need to use is RELATED() with a column reference.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft 
The two tables have a many to many relationship, should I connect them on a many to many? There's nothing that DealerProduct has that can be used as a one to many

Comment: @OzanSen
Can only use RELATED() if ProductPrice was the many to one in DealerProduct. But they are not directly related.

Comment: Is (DealerId,ProductId) unique in both tables?  If so merge them into a single table in Power Query, or use COMBINEVALUES to create a single-column key and relate them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/combinevalues-function-dax